# Is it possible to access a remote computer on a different network using Remmina and Vino and how?

Tags: linux-mint, vnc, remote-desktop, remmina

I am using Linux Mint 14. Remmina and Vino is installed on my system. Now I want to access another remote computer (which is in different network and IP is not static).

I only want to use VNC.

Is it possible with Remmina and Vino? If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to make sure the remote system you are trying to access is running VNC server. Without that, you are out of luck.
Second, the router that the remote system is sitting behind, is allowing requests coming to port 5900-5910 range and directing them straight to the system you are trying to reach.
Last but not the least, the network your current computer is in, should be allowing outgoing connections to port 5900-5910

I am under the impression that you are trying to reach your desktop at home from a public wireless access point (like Starbucks) or from your work place. If you satisfy the conditions above and you know the dynamic IP address of your remote system (if you wish, you can use a free service provided by `no-ip.com` or alike to circumvent this concern), you should be able to access your remote desktop.

I am not very familiar with remmina or vino, but using the freely available VNC-Server and vncviewer applications, you can accomplisy what you are looking for.

Comment: Note that "only using VNC" in the above scenario is unlikely to be secure.  The original VNC protocol does not implement encryption (nor does it authenticate the server), so it is vulnerable to interception.  This is the same class of issue as exploited by Firesheep.  Except instead of breaking your security of individual authenticated websites, it breaks your security on the target computer.  As a secure tunnelling protocol, SSH is usually the solution on linux workstations.

Comment: @Mel_Burslan - Thanks for your reply. You are right I'm trying to access my home computer from my office.

To get my IP for my remote system, I write on google "what is my ip" and it shows me a IP. Can I use this IP to connect to that computer?

Comment: yes that address is your public IP address but it doesn't actually belong to your PC. it belongs to your router (unless of course your cable/dsl modem is directly connected to this machine). So you need to be able to configure so-called virtual servers on your router. Which basically means, if a request comes to this IP address at a certain port or port range, forward the requests to your home PC inside your home network. If you googe it you will see how it is done for your particular router. Every router has a different interface to configure those. So I can not give you a how-to here.

Comment: also, since you are connecting from your work place, make sure your workplace network admins do not block outgoing traffic on ports 5900-5910. If they do, you are out of luck, unless you can convince them to remove the blocking.

Comment: @Mel_Burslan - Now I understand this fact better. But there are more than 30 computers under that public IP. So, when I'm requesting to connect a with specific username & password under that public IP. Then my request will reach that IP and will search for that specific username & password. When it find any match with username & password,it'll connect. If my concept is correct, please say YES.

Comment: when you say there are 30 computers under that public IP, are you referring to your home network, having 30 computers inside it ? If this is the case, re you the administrator to the router in front of these computers ? Or 30 computers refer to your work place network ? I am not quite clear where you stand.

Comment: @Mel_Burslan, actually, my home pc using a modem (mobile broadband). That's my WAN IP and my PC IP is not same and there is 30 computers in this area.

Comment: if the mobile broadband modem is connected to your PC directly (say via USB) then your IP address should be unique to that machine. But if you are talking about a mobile broadband wi-fi access point, which is serving 30 or so PCs, than yes, your WAN-IP or public IP (what google shows you) will be different than that of your PC. Which one is your case ? USB connected boradband modem or wi-fi access point thru a broadband device ?

Comment: @Mel_Burslan, my home PC is connected with a USB modem (WiMAX network or 4G). Whatever it is, I can connect with my home PC now from my office, using WAN IP of my home connection. It can connect using Remmina and Vinagre, and both of them are working great. Thanks to you again for your help.